# NSCollectionView - custom view item either isn't wired or won't select

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, nscollectionview

Here's how I create the collection view item:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: NSCollectionView, itemForRepresentedObjectAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> NSCollectionViewItem {
    let item = collectionView.makeItemWithIdentifier("ViewItem", forIndexPath: indexPath)
    guard let collectionViewItem = item as? ViewItem else {
        return item
    }
    return collectionViewItem
}
```

If I don't register the custom class ViewItem, selection works! As expected, IBOutlets are nil and I can't modify the object.

Before `reloadData` in `viewDidLoad`, if I use `self.collectionView.registerClass(ViewItem.self, forItemWithIdentifier: "ViewItem")`, then IBOutlets are wired, and I can change the object, but no selection seems to work.

```
func collectionView(collectionView: NSCollectionView, didSelectItemsAtIndexPaths indexPaths: Set<NSIndexPath>) {
    print("Select")
}
```

Never gets called. ViewItem is a xib with base class `NSCollectionViewItem`. It has a single label (for now, to test this to get it working), and I've changed no default options.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding

```
collectionView.selectable = YES
```

Hope it works for you.